# Google+: List History of +1ed Postings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-plus

I'm searching for a way to get all +1ed postings (not URLs) on Google+ to write an chrome extension to make them better browsable. There is a page in the Google+ settings, where I can find this log (https://plus.google.com/apps/activities) but i'd like to have it as a more useful view and maybe searchable.

I checked the Google+ API but did not find any API call for this. But since I'm in user context in my extension, maybe there is a undocumented call to get the +1 history out of Google+.